# React state not updating after async await call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React Hooks and the useEffect to get data from an API. I need to make 2 consecutive calls. If I console.log the response directly, it shows the correct response, but when I console.log the state, its empty and its not updating. What am I doing wrong?

```
const [describeFields, setDescribeFields] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  await axios
    .all([
      axios.get("someUrl"),
      axios.get("someotherUrl")
    ])
    .then(
      axios.spread((result1, result2) => {
        console.log(result1.data.result.fields); //shows correct response
        setDescribeFields(result1.data.result.fields);
        console.log(describeFields);  //shows empty array      
      })
    );
};
fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Note that there are [plans to remove `axios.all` and `axios.spread`](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042) since it's just replacing `Promise.all` and the spread operator.

Comment: Also, the `async/await` is useless here since you're already using promises.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, how can i write it correctly?

Comment: `useEffect(() => { Promise.all([axios.get(), axios.get()]).then(/**/); }, []);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not be displayed just after that if you want to see latest changes just console log before `return` statement as setState is async your console.log run before then `setState`

```
const [describeFields, setDescribeFields] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  await axios
    .all([
      axios.get("someUrl")
      axios.get("someotherUrl")
    ])
    .then(
      axios.spread((result1, result2) => {
        console.log(result1.data.result.fields); //shows correct response
        setDescribeFields(result1.data.result.fields);
      })
    );
};
fetchData();
}, []);

console.log(describeFields); //Check here
return(

)
```

Note : [] array in useEffect means it will run only one time. If you want to update as long as variable changes then add it as dependency.

Here is working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-thunder-et83o

Comment: yep, that was it, thanks. ill choose it as a solution 5 mins later. Problem was that i had a mistake on displaying the data and i was  thinking its not updating at all

Comment: Its common mistake and can be done by anyone. Happy coding :-)